# Javascript works on localhost but not on live server

Tags: javascript

The Javascript works on localhost but not the live server, and I can't figure out how to address the path.

Head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/modernizr.min.js'></script>
```

At the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/script.js'></script>
```

On live server the console shows these errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) - /js/isotope.min.js (and similar 17 times)

Content pages are not able to reference the functions in any of the .js files, the browser is looking for a separate file instead reading it from the script.js. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think in script.js or any js file ,other js files are being referenced. So,as those files are referenced and the file is not found ,therefore a filenotfound error

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackO! Could you feed us with more information - what production/local server do you use?

Comment: @Kristianmitk how could it be related to "what production/local server do you use"?

Comment: @flavalanch can you please show the files you have in your js folder locally?

Comment: @quirimmo they may be differently configured ( - e.g index rerouting - ) don't assume a php development server will serve you the same as apache

Comment: Can you see the content of your _.js_ files in the browser window if you type their address directly in the address bar or you see a 404?

Comment: @EhsanT Yes, those that are in the folder, like: js/script.js. But the browser is looking for this for example: js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js, while this imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js should be inside the script.js

Comment: It's getting a little complicated. Please edit your question and add the content of _script.js_ to it. Also if possible, add a simple file structure of your project to your question. Like the location of one of your _HTML_ files along with the _js_ files you are referencing inside the _HTML_ file. And then please add the content of that _HTML_ file to your question as well...